# Get the value of many childs inside a parent json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

this is just a fraction of a bigger json object, and I want to extract only the triggerid of every child object, I can get the first triggerid with the following line,

```
 var gettrigger = eventdata.result[0].relatedObject.triggerid;
```

but how can I get the triggerid of every child and addit to an array?

```
var event = {
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "result":[
      {
         "eventid":"964101",
         "name":"unreachable last 5 minutes",
         "severity":"0",
         "acknowledged":"0",
         "clock":"1578456800",
         "hosts":[
            {
               "hostid":"11195",
               "name":"Vi-console"
            }
         ],
         "relatedObject":{
            "triggerid":"23630"
         }
      },
      {
         "eventid":"964091",
         "name":"unreachable last 5 minutes",
         "severity":"0",
         "acknowledged":"0",
         "clock":"1578456695",
         "hosts":[
            {
               "hostid":"11180",
               "name":"Net-fluid"
            }
         ],
         "relatedObject":{
            "triggerid":"23375"
         }
      },
      {
         "eventid":"964090",
         "name":"high cpu usage",
         "severity":"3",
         "acknowledged":"0",
         "clock":"1578456675",
         "hosts":[
            {
               "hostid":"11188",
               "name":"Net-OFFICE"
            }
         ],
         "relatedObject":{
            "triggerid":"23503"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, like this:

```
var arr = eventdata.result.map(data => data.relatedObject.triggerid);
```

```js
var eventdata = {
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "result":[
      {
         "eventid":"964101",
         "name":"unreachable last 5 minutes",
         "severity":"0",
         "acknowledged":"0",
         "clock":"1578456800",
         "hosts":[
            {
               "hostid":"11195",
               "name":"Vi-console"
            }
         ],
         "relatedObject":{
            "triggerid":"23630"
         }
      },
      {
         "eventid":"964091",
         "name":"unreachable last 5 minutes",
         "severity":"0",
         "acknowledged":"0",
         "clock":"1578456695",
         "hosts":[
            {
               "hostid":"11180",
               "name":"Net-fluid"
            }
         ],
         "relatedObject":{
            "triggerid":"23375"
         }
      },
      {
         "eventid":"964090",
         "name":"high cpu usage",
         "severity":"3",
         "acknowledged":"0",
         "clock":"1578456675",
         "hosts":[
            {
               "hostid":"11188",
               "name":"Net-OFFICE"
            }
         ],
         "relatedObject":{
            "triggerid":"23503"
         }
      }
   ]
};

var arr = eventdata.result.map(data => data.relatedObject.triggerid);

console.log(arr)
```